# How to remove components from Three20 library correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, three20

Currently I have a need to use "TTStyledTextLabel".  However it's very heavy so I attempted to try to remove parts that I don't need.  FOr example, I don't need all the photo related stuff, view controller stuff, etc.

I was trying to do it two ways, one is to modify individual modules in xcode (like remove files), then add it to my project.  Second was to try to add individual files from 320 into my project.  However, second option got out of hand very quick, as it pulls in pretty much all the files from 320 lib.

Is there a way to do this more intelligently?  For example, I am not too sure with XCode static library compilation method, so I am not even sure if commenting out files and removing them from for example Three20UI component, then adding it to my project is the right way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after trying it in bunch of different ways, here's how I did mine.

I started by:
1) adding all project files from three20 into my project.  i think there's 7 modules to 320.
2) start trimming away by removing leaf stuff.  For example, photo viewers, etc.  Make sure 
not to remove some ambiguous stuff.  if you don't know what it does, dont' remove it yet.
3) once you think you trimmed each 320 projects down, then start looking at removing a whole project.
4) I ended up removing 320network first, of course this will break bunch of stuff, compiler will go nuts.  I just went through them and removed them one by one - like comment out code that calls 320network code (image views all have this to cache url images).  Sometimes I comment the whole methods, or sometimes just comment out the offending line.  doesn't really matter since you will most likely remove this from proj as well.
5) Once I was able to remove network, I went ahead with UINavigation one as well - then do the same - fix compile errors.
6) Slowly and carefully repeat.

I needed to use TTStyledTextLabel, and I think I got really lucky.  I ended up with 320 libraries sizes totaling up to about 1 meg.  I got 320UI to be about 100kb, and last remaining module that I can't get down further is 320Style.

Anyway, sorry for sucky process, but it is what I did..

Comment: If you needed to simply have styled text, look around for sample code that uses NSAttributed strings.  There are a number of small projects.  Three20 is ANCIENT at this point.

Comment: I did look at other options.  However, they are all for english language only.  I plan to support all languages, then the drawing code fails as they don't handle font fall back.  three20 is the only library I found so far that can handle all languages mixed or not. Do you have example that works with multilanguage nsattributed strings?

Comment: Hmm, that is an interesting twist.  Sorry, I'm not sure what would except to say that CoreText is very powerful, and should be able to handle that just fine...